# Incorrectly colored arrows in powerline themes in oh-my-zsh on Windows

Tags: oh-my-zsh, conemu

I successfully installed Oh-My-Zsh on Bash on Windows, except for one annoying issue: every time I used a powerline theme, the arrows have their own colors. I imagine this is a problem with the terminal, but I can't figure out what settings I need to change. This problem exists both in the default terminal and in Cmder / ConEmu.

[image: Terminal screen shot image]

Comment: Try combo of ConEmu + wsl-bridge

Comment: @Maximus Thank you for this tip, wsl-bridge solved quite a few problems for me. I still had trouble with Unicode characters on certain fonts in ConEmu, so I switched to wsltty, and as of now everything works perfectly!